# Discord API 10062? how to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So part of my code:

```js
// Check if the user is in any of the allowed groups and has the correct rank
const addedRoles = [];
const removedRoles = [];
const groupRanks = {}; // Keep track of highest priority rank for each group

for (const rank of ranks) {
    const groupId = rank.groupId;
    const rankId = rank.rankId;
    const allowedRanks = [rankId];
    try {
        const inGroup = await noblox.getRankInGroup(groupId, await noblox.getIdFromUsername(robloxUsername));
        if (inGroup && allowedRanks.includes(inGroup)) {
            const priority = rank.priority || 0; // Use priority specified in rank data or 0 if not defined
            const existingRank = groupRanks[groupId] || { rankId: 0, priority: -1 }; // Default to rankId 0 and priority -1 if group not found
            if (priority > existingRank.priority) {
                const rolesArray = rank.roleIds;
                const template = rank.template;
                for (const roleId of rolesArray) {
                    const role = guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.id === roleId);
                    if (role && !guildMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
                        await guildMember.roles.add(role);
                        addedRoles.push(role);
                    }
                }
                const nickname = template + " " + robloxUsername;
                await guildMember.setNickname(nickname);
                groupRanks[groupId] = { rankId, priority };
            }
        } else {
            const rolesArray = rank.roleIds;
            for (const roleId of rolesArray) {
                const role = guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.id === roleId);
                if (role && guildMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
                    await guildMember.roles.remove(role);
                    removedRoles.push(role);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Ok so first like its need to do its changing the temple to the highest priority but after it's changed to the highest it's changing to the lowest and my bot just dies

(I'm using Node.js v18.15.0m Discord js v14)

Database picture:
[image]